# What are the HTML elements for Google Sheet cells?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-sheets

Is there a way to find the ID and Class Name of a single Google Sheets cell and modify the CSS?

[image]

Comment: Can't you do that using gsheet formulas and formatting?

Answer (score 0):

They use `canvas` for the cells. Probably there is a way how to select a cell you like. But I don't think it's a good idea to find it out from inspect. Consulting the documentation could be a better idea.

Comment: Surely none of those HTML elements are documented anywhere.

Comment: I was referring to docs for google sheet. I see people make plugins for that, hence there must be documentation, but I don't know if it talks about the question you asked.

Comment: Google Sheets documentation does not concern the implementation of their browser interface, which is not documented and subject to change at any moment. Using "inspect" is the only option, with the understanding that anything built on top of that may break any day.

Comment: Then you can only try to find the script which draws the canvas and try to figure it out.